# How often do you have to cite a source when stating that you follow someone's work at the beginning of the section?

Tags: citations, plagiarism, citation-style

I am writing my thesis at this point and I have some sections, which started as follows:

Throughout this section we follow  \cite[Section 3.2.1]{...} for solving ...

I am wondering whether I have to cite the same source more than only the one time at the beginning of the section or not. This is because I use his/her work through the whole section.

Any explananation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clearly state that a certain section of the text is based on a named reference you do not need to repeat the reference again as long as you do not insert another source somewhere. The basic rule is generally that a reference is valid from its appearance until a different reference is encountered OR you reach the end of a paragraph. Normally references are not carried across paragraphs. So as long as you can clearly explain to the reader what in the text comes from the reference in mind, then you should be in good shape.

Another technique, used in papers that frequently reference a specific paper, is to create some abbreviation for the reference such as (Smith and Jones, 1975, henceforth referred to as "S&J") and then use S&J instead fo the reference itself. This is not a frequent solution but can be a solution where the paper otherwise becomes full of the same repeating refereence.

In the end, the important aspect is to make sure there is no question as to from where the information comes.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful here. There is another consideration. Saying that you "follow" a source doesn't give you license to copy their words. Nor does it give you license to paraphrase so much of the work that the copyright owner sees a violation, which they would if they believe that you lessen the value of the original.

Plagiarism and copyright are, in some sense, orthogonal, and you need to consider both.

If you copy words, quote and cite each or make it clear that all quotations are from the same place.